# Appropriate uses of the AUC score in evaluating a binary classifier

Tags: probability, classification, auc

I am accustom to using area under the curve (AUC) score to evaluate classification of binary distinctions, but it is not clear to me if there is value in evaluating the AUC score of a binary distinction with a predicted probability (of the class). The binary/binary case seems standard. Is it ever appropriate or useful to evaluate the binary/probability case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate a [probabilistic classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_classification), you'll probably want a [proper scoring rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule#Proper_scoring_rules), which, roughly speaking, gives more credit to more accurate probabilities. AUC, when used as a scoring rule, is not proper.

Comment: In terms of machine learning optimization scorers could you suggest some common 'proper scoring rules' for probability prediction from a binary classifier? I found the brier_score_loss in scikit-learn. Is one more commonly used?

Comment: @MyopicVisage The linked Wikipedia article mentions the three usual choices: the Brier score (also known as squared error), log loss, and spherical loss.

Comment: Attempting to predict the probability appears then to return to the scorer used in regression. Thanks!